# How can I deselect a default printer in Windows 7 and get back to no printer selected as default?

Tags: windows-7, printing

I'm working on a bug in an application where the user is getting an exception if they attempt to print without a default printer selected. I'm trying to recreate that, but I have a default printer set and can not get it unselected without selecting a different one.

Is there a way to get back to a point where no printer is set as the default?

I'm on Windows 7 Professional.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable [Let windows manage my default printer](https://www.normanbauer.com/2011/03/11/how-to-disable-windows-7s-default-printer-management/)

Delete (or rename):

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows->Device
```

Restart the print spooler.

It should work.. I had to fix the same EXACT bug in the past.. I *think* that is what I did to repro but it has been a while.

Comment: Manage Default Printers is not available as an option for me. But I'm thinking your answer here would work if I had admin right s to my machine.  Thanks.